# No sound when attaching a flash file in a movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a flash file with sounds in it. i cant hear the sounds when attaching it in another flash file

```
loadMovie("rlvl3.swf",_root.drop);
```

but this works

```
loadMovie("rlvl3.swf",_root);
```

Can i still use the above code?

Comment: Man, you really should move to AS3...

Comment: i will, but this project was already written in as2

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to use this code to play the sound

```
var snd:Sound = new Sound(this);
snd.attachSound("r3smile");
snd.start();
```

this will not work..

```
var snd:Sound = new Sound();
snd.attachSound("r3smile");
snd.start();
```